# Syntax error on MySQL trigger when only updating one column

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a MySQL trigger that fires when the column user_email is updated in the table wp_users, but it's failing. I'm getting a syntax error just before the second BEGIN, but it looks fine to me. What am I missing?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `email_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `wp_users` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN IF NEW.user_email <> OLD.user_email
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO `bfintranet`.`intranet_staff_updates` (`staff_update_ID`, `user_ID`, `updated_value`, `new_value`, `old_value`, `update_datetime`) 
        VALUES (NULL, NEW.ID, 'user_email', NEW.user_email, OLD.user_email, now()) 
    END 
END;
```

Without the one column only condition, it works fine (but doesn't achieve what I want it to):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `email_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `wp_users` 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO `bfintranet`.`intranet_staff_updates` (`staff_update_ID`, `user_ID`, `updated_value`, `new_value`, `old_value`, `update_datetime`) VALUES (NULL, NEW.ID, 'user_email', NEW.user_email, OLD.user_email, now())
```

It appears to error on whatever comes after the IF, regardless of what comes after or what the IF condition is.

Comment: I do not see [`END IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html).

Comment: Error is " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN INSERT INTO `bfintranet`.`intranet_staff_updates` (`staff_update_ID`, `u' at line 5"

Comment: @PM77-1 - where should the END IF go?

Comment: Posted as an answer. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

First you should review the MySQL `IF...THEN...END IF` syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Also with complex queries like this you need to temporarily override the default delimiter so you can use semi-colons within the trigger.

This should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `email_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `wp_users` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN IF NEW.user_email <> OLD.user_email
    THEN 
        INSERT INTO `bfintranet`.`intranet_staff_updates` (`staff_update_ID`, `user_ID`, `updated_value`, `new_value`, `old_value`, `update_datetime`) 
        VALUES (NULL, NEW.ID, 'user_email', NEW.user_email, OLD.user_email, now());
    END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That inserts perfectly, and works as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix this particular error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `email_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `wp_users` 
CREATE TRIGGER `email_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `wp_users` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.user_email <> OLD.user_email
    THEN
        INSERT INTO `bfintranet`.`intranet_staff_updates` (`staff_update_ID`, `user_ID`, `updated_value`, `new_value`, `old_value`, `update_datetime`) 
        VALUES (NULL, NEW.ID, 'user_email', NEW.user_email, OLD.user_email, now()) 
    END IF 
END;
```